# CodeModuleManager cannot allocate space for the module

Tags: blackberry, java-me, auto-update

I am trying to write an app that will download and install `cod` files.

I have the line:

```
CodeModuleManager.createNewModule(codData.length, codData, codData.length);
```

which is expected to return a module handle (which is an int). However, it returns 0 that means space cannot be allocated for the module to be intalled. I searched a bit but coulndt really find any info about what may be causing this. Any ideas ?

Comment: Two things to check: 1) there is sufficient application memmory for the module, and the module does not exceed the maximum size (a COD file can be bigger than the maximum module size; 2) if running on the device ensure your application is signed and that it has APPLICATION MANAGEMENT permission.

Comment: How do I add those permissions ? I think I maned to install the code file but I know get the error that my app has verfification errors. Should I pre-sign the cod file ?

Comment: If the COD file accesses signed APIs then it will have to be signed to run, but that will have an effect after installation. Coe module management APIs are signed so the application installing the module must be signed and have permission. Permission can be granted by the user or by the BES if the device is activated on a BES. Niether signatures nor permission are needed on the simulator.

Comment: Thanks for all your help and suggestions @Richard! In the end, I found it more convenient to use the .jad file instead of trying to install .cod files direclty by myself

Comment: There are many benefits to using the JAD file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

1. I used the COD files inside the deliverables/web directory
2. When the COD file is above some size it is partitioned into 2 (or more) cod files. In my case there were two COD files. One was named abc.cod and the other one was abc-1.cod. You need to have both cod files in order to make the installation. (which was the real problem)
3. I noticed that in the deliverables/standard folder there is only 1 cod file which is probably the case that it is not splitted into 2 parts and, thus, the CodeModuleManager is not able to allocate space for it as a whole (thus partitioning is necessary afterall)

However, even after this you can encounter problems such as the icon of your application getting disappeared when you overwrite cod files (ie. when you try to update your app which already exists).

I found it more convenient to work with the `.jad` file. Just set up the right mime types in your directory and put the `jad` and `cod` files in there. Then open your `jad`file using the browser and your app should be automatically and smoothly installed/updated by the OS itself.

Hope this proves helpful for someone else